# Problem with showing a UserForm after termination

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**1st, what i want to do:**

I have a main UserForm, on that form i have a button to show secondary UserForm. When i click on that button, i want main form to be hidden. When i'm done with with work on the secondary form, i want to close it and show the main form again.

**2nd, what i have so far (relevant code):**

Main form  code:

```
Private Sub createFastButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    formSec.Show
End Sub
```

Secondary form code:

```
Private Sub cancelButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    formMain.Show
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    formMain.Show
End Sub
```

**3rd, the problem:**

If i use ControlButtons to navigate between forms, all works as intended. But if i use the "X" close window button on the secondary form and try to open it again from main form, it loses all functionality (main form works fine). It just shows the secondary form as i see it, when i use "View Object" in VBA editor. None of the buttons work and none of the intended boxes and labels are filled. Even the "X" button doesn't work. For me it seems obvious, that the problem is with unloading of secondary form. I tried to replace `Me.Hide` in secondary form with `Unload Me` and exactly same thing happens, as if i press the "X" button. So i need to do something with `Sub UserForm_Terminate()`, i tried to add `Me.Hide` there and as expected, it did nothing.

I there a solution to my problem?

Thx in advance.

Comment: 1) when you "launch" the 2nd form the first time, is it being pre-filled with data? form where? with which code? 2) when you "close" the 2nd form do you want to keep its data in order to be available for a subsequent "life"?

Comment: 1) some of it yes. From a table in excel. Some lines like `TextBox1.Value = shData.Range("A3").Value`. 2) i don't want to keep the data in the secondary form. The 1st thing i do, is i clear the secondary form, when i open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main routine, calling Main Form:

```
With New formMain
    .Show
End With
```

main form, calling secondary form

```
Private Sub createFastButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    With New formSec
        .Show
    End With
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

secondary form

```
Private Sub cancelButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
   If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

no need for `UserForm_Terminate()` in secondary form, unless for unsaid needs

Comment: Ty, that is almost exactly what i needed. I used the code for `QueryClose` from xidgel, since i also need to hide secondary form.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the "X" raises a `QueryClose` event that you need to handle, e.g.:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
        ' Add more code here to respond to form close event
    End If
End Sub
```

See [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/) for a very helpful explanation.

Comment: Ty, that is indeed a very nice read. I will read it properly later, when i can fully concentrate on it. Already learned a lot.